# How can I delete an entity when I have no DbSet for that type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using a `DbContext` that has been provided and I cannot change it.

Edited for brevity, the context contains two types

```
public class LogPost {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LogReply> Replies { get; set; }

    public LogPost() {
        Replies = new List<LogReply>();
    }
}

public class LogReply {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

There is no `DbSet<LogReply>` to work with, only a `DbSet<LogPost>`. If I try removing the reply from the `post.Replies` collection, it throws an exception about foreign key properties not being null (as expected).

How can I delete a reply?

Comment: Although I have a solution I'm sharing I will accept other answers if they're better!

Comment: Not tried this, but is it possible to extend the context? Inherit from it and add your own DbSet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you are unable to change the existing `DbContext` implementation, but the method to create a `DbSet<T>` for a `DbContext` is public (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx)).

So you could try the following:

```
using(var db = new Context())
{
    var post = db.LogPosts.First(p => p.ID == postID);
    var reply = post.Replies.First(r => r.ID == replyID);

    var logReplies = db.Set<LogReply>();
    logReplies.Remove(reply);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I am using is to get the `DbEntityEntry` for the entity and manually marking it as deleted.

```
using (var db = new Context()) {
    var post = db.LogPosts.First(p => p.ID == postID);
    var reply = post.Replies.First(r => r.ID == replyID);
    db.Entry(reply).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```